# Do I need to encrypt data when exchanging information via SSL?

Tags: php, ssl, encryption

I’m creating a service where I have the data encrypted in my database, but need to send it to an application (via API requests). My question is: do I need to send the data encrypted throughout the connection (using OpenSSL private and public keys) or does SSL do all that stuff? So can I keep the data safe when interacting with applications and sending the data as it is (non-encrypted)?

Can someone provide more information about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL encrypts all the payload so you do not need to encrypt your data within SSL. It will be decrypted at the other end of the network.